# identifier not being set in initWithtFrame method in custom NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've set the identifier (under User interface item identifier) to a string value but when I try to print it out in the initWithFrame it's null. When I print it out in the drawRect it's set. I'm guessing it hasn't been loaded from the nib yet? in what event would I be able to look at the value of identifier, preferably before it gets to the paint, or maybe there's a method I should call to load the value?

tia

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       ...
       NSLog(@"ident: %@", [self identifier]); // prints (null) here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is initialized, but the identifier is not loaded from nib.  Try NSLog () in awakeFromNib instead.